# macchanger's effect disappears when wifi connection is back up

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ip, mac-address

When I installed `macchanger` package I set it to change mac address everytime an interface is down. However I noticed that my IP address was not changing. So I examined my mac address.

When connected to router

```
ip addr
1: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.7/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 7175sec preferred_lft 7175sec
```

When Wi-Fi is disabled

```
ip addr
1: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 67:89:ab:cd:ef:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr ab:cd:ef:01:23:45
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

When Wi-Fi is reenabled

```
ip addr
1: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

When reconnected to router

```
ip addr
1: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.7/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 7160sec preferred_lft 7160sec
```

When I try to change mac address while Wi-Fi is disabled

```
macchanger -r wlo1
Current MAC:   67:89:ab:cd:ef:01 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 (unknown)
New MAC:       23:45:67:89:ab:cd (unknown)
```

When I try to change mac address manually when Wi-Fi is on but not connected

```
macchanger -r wlo1
Current MAC:   67:89:ab:cd:ef:01 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 (unknown)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
```

When I try to change mac address manually when connected to Wi-Fi

```
macchanger -r wlo1
Current MAC:   ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: ab:cd:ef:01:23:45 (unknown)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
```

As you can see the change is reverted whenever I reconnect to Wi-Fi. How can I make it persist?

Comment: That's probably done by your network configuration tool (eg: NetworkManager). You should state which tool it is in the question. macchanger is probably redundant if the tool can handle this itself.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/how-to-permanently-change-mac-address.html